# How to use a "backup node" in Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a job that gets triggered automatically, let's call it `JobA` and I have two nodes `NodeA` and `NodeB`.
I want `JobA` to always run **only** on `NodeA`, but if `NodeA` is offline I want it to run on `NodeB`.
How can is set this up?

Currently `JobA` only uses `NodeA`. If the node if offline the build is not executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be something like below. more details you can explore [here](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#agent)

```
pipeline {
  agent { label 'NodeA || NodeB' }
  stages {
     stage('stage-one') {
       steps {
          ....
       }
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried exactly this, but it does not work for me. I found a solution that works for me:
I created a `JobB` which is able to check if nodes are online. `JobB` starts `JobA` with different parameters depending on which nodes are online.
I know it's only a workaround but that's the only way that I got it running.